# How to avoid multiple definitions when defining test doubles

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to define a test double for a function that I am trying to define. It probably doesn't make much difference, but I am using IAR for a Cortex ARM M3 with the included compiler.

In the function that I'm trying to test, I make a call to a function that sends a message over a serial interface.
Here is some pseudocode to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish :

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#include "MessageController.h"
#else
#include "FakeMessageController.h"
#endif

uint8 FunctionToTest(....)
{
  uint8 data[100];
  uint8 error;

  //Prepare data to send here
  SendMessage(data);

  if (error)  return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

I have created a copy of the original file that contained the SendMessage function and made mofications to it in another file. I thought that I could change the function that is called through the #ifdef statements, however, that is ot the case.

I get the following error for multiple definitions

```
Error[Li006]: duplicate definitions for .... ; in "......\Tests\Debug\Obj\MessageController.o", and "....\dvlp\Debug\Tests\Debug\Obj\FakeMessageController.o"
```

I fully understand the reason why the linker is giving my this error, but is there a workaround to this problem? Or some way of tricking the linker into using the correct function?
I can't modify the test function since it is a link to the original file in my project.

Comment: Is the `SendMessage` an inline or a macro? Are those header file included into other `c` files?

Comment: Remove the _definition_ in `FakeMessageController.h` and instead only _declare_ it there. Then when you link against `MessageController.o`, the real object is used.

Comment: @LPs : SendMessage is a function that is normally defined in the MessageController.c file. However, I want to use the SendMessage function defined in FakeMessageController.c when I am unit testing

Comment: @inetknght : how does removing the definition in FakeMessageController.h make sure that I link with the function in FakeMessageController.c?

Comment: Ok. What is included into your IAR project? If there are both files remove the one or put its code under undef as done for header.

Comment: What I meant is that change the name of the header does not change the compiler command or linker to compile and link a file with the same name. Compiler will compile all sources added to project. If into those files there are two function with the same name, linker does not know which one to choose.

Comment: Have a different compilation/link target when unit testing, and have the fake .c file for the unit test target, and the real one for the real target.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help. I found my own solution.

I wrapped all my code in MessageController.c with a #ifndef

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST
// All the code in the MessageController.c
#endif
```

Inside MessageController.h, I used this trick:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#include "FakeMessageController.h"
#else

// original header content

#endif
```

It's not the cleanest in my opinion, but it works for me.